# change comboBox values based on click i another

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have two functions with the first one filling a comboBox with the tables within my SQL Database, this it below:

```
   private void FillCombo()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
                }
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And I have another one which is filling the second comboBox based on the value from the previous function's combobox. This is it below

```
    async void fillLiguanea()
    { 
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();

            try
            {

                string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBox1.Text;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                comboBox2.BeginUpdate();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string scode = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("code"));
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);
                }
                comboBox2.EndUpdate();
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }}
```

What am trying to do is to refresh the "fillLiguanea" function's comboBox value based on the table selected in the "fillCombo" function. Eg. if there are tables with the name "cat" and "dog" in my comboBox that is filled by "fillLiguanea" then when selected it should automatically change the comboBox which is filled by "fillLiguanea" with the various cat or dog breeds.

I was reading and saw something about the SelectionChangeCommitted event. Is this the way to go or is there a better way to do this?

I've achieved this through a refresh button that targets my second comboBox but I would rather eliminate the use of buttons for the user

Comment: Yup, I'd just use one of the following events "SelectionChangeCommitted" or "SelectedIndexChanged" or "SelectedValueChanged". Note that clearing the combobox won't raise any of the aforementioned events.

Comment: How would I go about including it? Am not sure on its implementation

Comment: I have `if(comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted==)`
Am not sure what am testing @RoyalPotato

Comment: I believe that to be most easily answer via screenshots. And apparently I can't add those to comments. So I'll have to write up an answer real quick.

Comment: @RoyalPotato ok I await your reply

Comment: @Jevon Can you say what's the main question in this post? Are you looking for a correct event between `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectionChangeCommitted`? Or the question is something else?

Comment: I figured it out and implemented it correcyly with SelectionChangeCommitted event.  That was the real issue

Comment: OK, good job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out being a simple solution. I just passed the comboBox from the fillCombo function into the fillLiguanea function and everything worked as I wanted. The two functions are listed below:

This is the fillCombo method which is populating from the SQL database to my comboBox called "comboBox4"

```
private void FillCombo()
    {



            comboBox4.Items.Clear();


            try
            {

                string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    con2.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ";
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                        comboBox4.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
                    }
                   // comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And this is my fillLiguanea method that updates the table based on the comboBox4 selection from my above  function.

```
  async void fillLiguanea()
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBox4.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            comboBox2.BeginUpdate();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string scode = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("code"));
                comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);
            }
            comboBox2.EndUpdate();
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            // comboBox2.Sorted = true;
        }
```

This is the important line of code:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBox4.Text;
```

With that everything was solved

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `events`.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

In short, an event is simply a way to trigger code by following the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Basically, an event represents multiple methods (I'll refer to these as "subscribing methods" as they "subscribe" to the event) that all get called when the event is raised from within the class it is defined in.
"Okay," you might say. "But when implementing a method to be called when the event is raised, how do I ensure I have the correct parameter types?".
[Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

A delegate represents the signature of a method (ie, the number of parameters/the parameter types/the method's return type). Each event is declared as being a type of a specific delegate.

For example, let's say you want an event that will call it's subscribing methods when an arbitrary message is received. How would you setup such a system using these things called "Events"?

1. Define your delegate

   `public delegate void MessageDelegate(string data);`

   This means (and enforces) that all subscribing methods to the event   **must** contain just one parameter and it's type must be `string`. Also that   each subscribing method must not return any value.
2. Define your event

   `public event MessageDelegate MessageReceived;`

   This says that we create an event (a collection of subscribed methods)   where each subscribing method must match the signature defined by the   delegate `MessageDelegate`.
3. Subscribe to your event (probably the part you're most interested in)
   To subscribe to the event (or add a method to the event's collection of subscribers) you first must create a method that matches the delegate:

   `private void OnMessageReceived(string msg)
   {
       //Do something with the received message.
   }`

   Then comes the actual subscribing:

   `MessageReceived += new MessageDelegate(OnMessageReceived)`.

   Now whenever the event is triggered our `OnMessageReceived` method will be called.
4. Finally, to trigger or **raise** the event (the process of calling each subscribing method) you simply can do:
   `MessageReceived("Hello World!")`

All that being said, how does this apply to your particular problem?
Well, the combobox control already contains the event. So you obviously don't have to define that yourself. That means all you're responsible for is subscribing to the event.

```
comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted);

private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Refresh combobox 2.
}
```

I recommend you put the actual subscription in the form's `Form_Load` event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted);
}
```

Now however, you must subscribe to the form's load event. Typically done in the constructor **after** the call to `InitializeComponent`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
}
```

You can of course, bypass the form load subscription

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted);
}
```

Lastly, if you're using the WindowsForms designer in Visual Studio:
Somewhere on the property pane there should be a way to view events for the selected control. Scroll down to your desired event. Double-click it. Visual studio should automatically create a method and subscribe to the event with the new method.

There is so much power behind events and delegates. I highly encourage you to do some reading up on them.
Sorry this wasn't as small as I envisioned but I thought I would try to explain *why* it works and not just "This is how it should be done.".